# Run code on active tab when popup button is pressed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension that will work on a website that displays charts using Highcharts. The extension will change colors of the data series. That's fine; I got it to run as an userscript with Tampermonkey. Now I want to build a browser extension.

Here's the very minimal code of my extension that should do the thing:

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Namely name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Descriptive description",
  "host_permissions":["https://some.url.com/*"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "scripting","activeTab"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Extension Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="runCodeButton">Run My Code</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('runCodeButton').onclick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query(
        {active:true, currentWindow:true},
        (tabs) => {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
                func: changeColors
            });
        }); 
};

function changeColors() {
    console.log("Running");
    var newColors = ["#FF6B6B","#FFFF00","#0082C8","#F58230","#FF0000","#46F0F0","#F032E6","#D2F53C","#FABEBE","#3CB44B",
                 "#008080","#E6BEFF","#AA6E28","#FFFAC8","#800000","#AAFFC3","#808000","#FFD7B4","#000080","#AAAAAA","#FFFFFF","#000000"];

    var chart = Highcharts.charts.slice(-1)[0];
    chart.series.forEach((series, i) => {
        series.update({
            color: newColors[i % newColors.length],
        });
    });
};
```

The extension logs "Running" on the console of the active tab as it should, but then returns an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`. Apparently the extension is not aware of all the objects in the active tab. I just need to access and modify the Highcharts object like I do with the userscript. I have more functionalities to implement, but they all need access to the Highcharts object on the active tab.

Comment: Add `world: 'MAIN'` to executeScript params object.

Comment: @wOxxOm that does it.